# Firefox/Chrome alignment differences with Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm curious if there's a simple CSS fix for an issue I'm running into.  It looks as though Firefox/OSX is including the width of it's scrollbar when determining the container width, and doesn't correctly right align the content (http://d.pr/i/fACK).  Chrome/OSX is working as I'd hope, and ignores the width of the scroller, and correctly aligns the content (http://d.pr/i/q02g).  I tried a few things like box-sizing and such, with no luck.

I've created a JS Fiddle, where you can review the issue on both Chrome/Safari and Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/jHVMU/2/

```
#container{
    width:600px;
}

#content{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#content ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}

#content ul li{
    width:30%;
    margin:0 5% 15px 0;
    height:150px;
    background:#000;
    float:left;
}

#content ul li:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: IE10 appears to take the scrollbar into account too, the right-aligned text is to the right of the boxes: http://i41.tinypic.com/4pv4lh.png

Comment: I don't really see a difference in the fiddle... is there something wrong with me?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, you could be on a PC.  I think Windows always adds the scrollbars

Comment: The problem is that you set the width in `%`. FF reserves the space for the scrollbar (it does not overlay) Chrome uses the system behaviour which (for OS X) only overlays the scrollbars. if you use `%` width you will always have problems with different scrollbar width on different systems.

Comment: @t.niese yeah, I suppose I could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/jHVMU/8/ - but it's sort of the opposite of what I want.  My #container may change widths, and I don't really want to manually set the width/height of the items every time.  This also really didn't solve the issue, as I had to remove the right padding on the UL to allow this to align.

Comment: @JoelEckroth i currently don't know how or if it could be solved with pure css. with js it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Used this solutions => http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/