# Firebug Layout Tab Inconsistent with Firefox Responsive Tool

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, responsive-design, firebug

The firebug Layout tab says that my viewport is 788x1280, but in the firefox responsive tool I have it is set to 804x1280. What could cause the two to be have different widths?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16px for the scrollbar which firefox deducts from the calculation of page width.

see some of the comments [On this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591463/firefox-chrome-alignment-differences-with-scrollbar)